# using string as argument in Bash script

Tags: bash

I'm new to BASH scripting. I am trying to use variables in commands. What I want is, for example, If the directory "resDir" had the files "patternOne.txt", "patternTwo.txt", "mylist.txt", I'd want the array "arr" to have both  "patternOne.txt" and "patternTwo.txt" in it. I am currently doing that this way:

```
resDir = /home/username/repo/results
str = "pattern"
arr = ($(ls resDir| grep str))
```

Is this correct or are there any glaring mistakes? Could someone explain when variables need quotations and when they don't?

Comment: If it works, it is correct.  If it doesn't, you should describe how it's behavior is not what you want.

Comment: @ScottHunter, ...well, the first part can be misleading, particularly in bash -- lots of things appear to work but have hidden gotchas or corner cases. But here, the details of how code doesn't work shouldn't be so card to figure out.

Comment: Suggested reading: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs, and the entirety of http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls (which showcases at least two of three major errors in this code).

Comment: ...also, the StackOverflow help center -- as it is, this isn't well-formed enough to be a good question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is one particular place worthy of focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
resDir=/home/username/repo/results
str="pattern"
arr=( "$resDir"/*"$str"* )
```

1. Whitespace MUST NOT be placed around the `=` on assignments; doing so makes the syntax no longer an assignment. (`resDir = /home/username/repo/results` runs a command named `resDir`, passing it `=` as its first argument).
2. Expansions are almost always safe to quote. Exceptions (such as the right-hand side of `[[ ]]` operators `=` and `=~`, when the expanded string should be treated as a glob pattern or regex rather than as literal text) are very rare. By contrast, bugs caused by failing to quote expansion are exceedingly commonplace.
3. `*`s MUST NOT be quoted, if you want them to trigger glob expansion rather than be treated literally.
4. `ls` MUST NOT be used in scripting.

---

By the way -- the resulting structure is an array. Below is an example of the syntax for expanding array contents:

```
printf '%q\n' "${arr[@]}"
```